# struts2 populate "value" object of map from Form post

Tags: java, jsp, dictionary, struts2, ognl

I'm using struts 2. I have an object that contains some booleans. I have a HashMap that contains many of the previous objects defined by some key.

In my jsp a table is populated with radio buttons. One line for each key of the map etc.
When I post back the form I want to save the options set by the user. But the map does not seem to get populated.

My code is like:

```
   MyObject ( with two boolean parameters )

    private Map<String, MyObject> ... (with getter & setter ).
```

in my jsp the html generated is:

```
    <input type="radio" name="myMap[123].booleanParameter1" id="someId" 
checked="checked" value="true">

etc
```

Can someone help on how the "name" of the radio button should be set so as struts can populate the map?

---

```
public class MyObject implements Serializable{

    private Boolean booleanParameter1;
    private Boolean booleanParameter2;

getters & setters here
}
```

---

```
Map<String,MyObject> myMap ... in Action
```

---

JSP...

```
 <s:iterator ...iterates default map values>

 <s:radio label="parameter1" name="myMap['%{key}'].booleanParameter1" list="#{'true':'Yes','false':'No'}" value="%{value.booleanParameter1}" />
<s:radio label="parameter2" name="myMap['%{key}'].booleanParameter2" list="#{'true':'Yes','false':'No'}" value="%{value.booleanParameter2}" />

</s:iterator>
```

Comment: Your key `123` isn't a string.

Comment: Didn't you populate it when your action is executed?

Comment: Should be `myMap['123'].booleanParameter1`.

Comment: @AleksandrM First, 123 can also be a string :). Second, I tried myMap['123'].booleanParameter1 still it didn't work. Any more suggestions?

Comment: You are not indicating that this is a string. Show your `MyObject` class and JSP form.

Comment: @AleksandrM Please check. i edited the original post.

Comment: It looks fine. Are you using default interceptor stack?

Comment: @AleksandrM No the interceptor stack has changes but I don't think that these changes would have any impact on this case.

Comment: Could you try with default stack? Just to be sure. :)

Comment: any other suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution found. The class "MyObject" did not have a Default Constructor. Struts/ognl needs the default constructor to create an object.